# Error message when using memoir and xcolor together

Tags: color, memoir

I'm running TeX Live 2013 on OS X (Mavericks) and I'm seeing a bizarre error when using `memoir` and `xcolor` together. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\title{A title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

yields the following error at compile time using `pdflatex`:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.3
```

whereas when I change the document class to `book`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\title{A title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I get no error and the document compiles fine.

I get the same error if I remove the `[usenames]` option as well. Am I just missing the right parameters to set, or is this a known problem ? As far as I can tell, I have the updated versions of the packages that go along with the 2013 distribution.

Notes: I have memoir 2013/05/30 v3.7b, and am running pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14. 
My version of xcolor has this information:

```
\def\XCfileversion{v2.00}%
\def\XCfiledate{2004/07/04}%
```

Comment: The "usenames" is obsolete options in recent xcolor package.

Comment: No errors here, with your example code, using TeX Live2013 updated 5 minutes ago. Can you run the `tlmgr` utility and make an update so see if the problem persists?

Comment: I have an updated memoir and xcolor package and just ran tlmgr. Still get the same error.

Comment: Well version 2.00 is not an updated version of `xcolor`; nor is it a version you are likely to find in any remotely recent version of TeX Live. Use `\listfiles` in your preamble and check the end of the `.log` to see what version you are actually loading.  (I also recommend examining the `.log` to find out from where on your system the package is being loaded.)

Comment: arggh. @jon's comment fixed the problem. I thought I was loading xcolor from the distribution, but in fact I was not. it was a careless slip. Now my question is answered, but not for a reason that might be useful in general. Should I merely request that it be closed ?

Comment: It might be considered 'too localized', I think, but I guess that depends on how unique your slip was.  Then again, if it's a problem of competing TeX installations, then there might already be a question for that as well.

Comment: Stray file on the system with an old version, off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized (stray file) and won't probably help other users.